# Open source projects with Java and Scala interaction

Tags: java, scala, computer-science

I'm going to give a talk about using Java and Scala together and I want to investigate some projects (large and small) which contains Java and Scala code.

If you know links to correspondent projects post them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://scala.sygneca.com/projects/start) on the Scala wiki is a good starting point...

Answer (score 0):

The various scala testing frameworks come to mind. They all have some integration with JUnit or TestNG

Answer (score 0):

Gimd is one example of small project: http://code.google.com/p/gimd/

Although development stalled for a while because I'm busy with other duties it already contains some examples of Scala<->Java integration. Notably:

- unit tests are written using junit
- Gimd is using JGit (library in Java) as underlying layer

While working on Gimd I found that using Java from Scala is mostly easy and seamless the contrary is not always true. It's not really a fault of Scala as it's simple manifestation that Java is a less expressive language.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know any open source project but I have worked on very large projects over the last few years that have java and scala interacting and my experience has been mostly very positive. If I had one piece of advice it would be to use [scala-javautils](http://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-javautils). It's a [life saver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519838/java-scala-interop-transparent-list-and-map-conversion/1520179#1520179) and is far better than the scala jcl code. Before we started using it trying to get some interactions involving collections was heart-breaking. However I'm led to believe 2.8 will solve this.

In general I find the interactions between scala and java very close to using one language.