# Loop through scala ListBuffer in java

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop, listbuffer

If it is possible, how would I loop through a ListBuffer from within java.
initialization of the ListBuffer (in scala)

```
var newModVersions: ListBuffer[NewModVersionEntry] = new ListBuffer[NewModVersionEntry]()
```

current smart for loop (in java)

```
for (VersionCheckHandler.NewModVersionEntry entry : XplosionCoreBL.newModVersions())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use `JavaConversions` for that:**

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;
//...
for (YourEntryClass entry : JavaConversions.asJavaIterable(yourListBuffer)) {
```

*(I've switched to placeholder types and vars, since otherwise the example would be less readable)*

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1625252/724361) to an "inverse" question for general info, and [this question+answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519838/java-scala-interop-transparent-list-and-map-conversion?rq=1) for an explanation of the design approach taken in the Scala library.